# How to open Excel file saved at specific location,Create a new tab as of last tab in a sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am not from software background and trying to write a macro to avoid repeated work that causes errors. Please feel free to suggest things that will make it better.I tried to pull pieces from different program from this site and make it work.

Thank you in advance.

Here is what I am trying to do.
a) I am trying to open Excel file(lets say file 2) saved at specific location from current file (Say file 1). ***Works***

b) Create a new tab in file 2 same as last tab in that file,***Works***

c) Re-name the created tab using 2 different cell from file 1.(Auto Rename would be good based on file 1 cells but I could only manage pop up that ask me to enter but doesn't rename the file). ***Doesn't Work/partially work***

d) Pop up to input Name and 2 more input in different cells(I can only get Your name how can I get 3 input in 3 different cells) ***Doesn't Work/partially work***

e) Copy 2 cells from file 1 and copy in file 2 newly created tab. ***Doesn't work***

Here is the code I tried to write.

```
Sub Filling_List()
Dim sPath As String, sFile As String, wb As Workbook, i As Integer

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sPath = "C:\Users\aricsonp\Desktop\Filling list macro\"
sFile = sPath & "ArF Filling List.xlsm"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = InputBox("New Name:")
If sName = "" Then Exit Sub

ActiveSheet.cell(3, "E") = InputBox("Your Name:")

' With ActiveSheet.Sheets("ArF Filling List (7)")
'.Range("B03").Value = uploader.Sheets("Que & Tsc Cal").Range("B02").Value
' .Range("B05").Value = uploader.Sheets("Que & Tsc Cal").Range("B01").Value
' End With


'Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some pointers.

1) Put **Option Explicit** at top so syntax and declarations are checked.
   This would force you to declare `sName` and `uploader` as well as set their values. `i` is also declared but not assigned.

2) Your code, as is, did rename the **sheet**. You assigned directly to the newly added sheet from the inputbox rather than storing in a variable.

```
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = InputBox("New Name:")
```

Assuming the variable `sName` was actually to hold this and that you want to grab this value from 2 cells in the workbook containing the code (i.e. **ThisWorkbook**) you are running:

```
sName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
```

You would probably want to declare and assign `ThisWorkbook` and worksheets you reference within as variables.

e.g.

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook
Dim ws1 as Worksheet 
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook 
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as appropriate
```

3) Avoid mixing **Sheets** and **Worksheets** collections. I prefer **Worksheets** collections unless you have Chart sheets present.

4) In most cases you will want to compare against **vbNullstring** rather than an empty string literal (""). It is faster to assign, uses less memory etc.

```
If sName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
```

5) Assigning more values to cells; add more inputboxes **AND** use `Cells` not Cell e.g.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, "E") = InputBox("Your Age:")
```

6) Adding more cells' values into the newly opened workbook, newly added sheet; use your `wb` and `sName` variables to ensure correct targeting:

```
With wb.Worksheets(sName)
```

7) You may want to declare each variable at the top on its own line i.e. avoid multiple declarations on one line. Makes it easier to debug and spot any implicit variants.

So, you might have something like the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Filling_List()

Dim sPath As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
'  Dim i As Integer ''not used
Dim sName As String 'add sName declaration
'Add declaration for uploader variable and set its value
Dim wb1 as Workbook
Dim ws1 as Worksheet 

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook 
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sPath = "C:\Users\aricsonp\Desktop\Filling list macro\"
sFile = sPath & "ArF Filling List.xlsm"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

'Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = InputBox("New Name:")

sName = ws1.Range("A1") & ws1.Range("B1") 'assign value from two cells

ActiveSheet.Name = sName

If sName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'compare against vbNullstring not empty string literal

With wb.Worksheets(sName)

    .Cells(3, "E") = InputBox("Your Name:")
    .Cells(4, "E") = InputBox("Your Age:")
    .Cells(5, "E") = InputBox("Your Occupation:")
    .Range("B03") = uploader.Worksheets("Que & Tsc Cal").Range("B02").Value2
    .Range("B05") = uploader.Worksheets("Que & Tsc Cal").Range("B01").Value2

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it almost worked. Very well explained. I used Option explicit but still it gives me error as "Compile error Variable not defined.  I see code stop at Uploader in last 2 lines where we try to pull value from 2 cells.I try to modify wb1 instead of uploader.

Comment: Thanks for the help it was very informative and well explained for someone like me who has little knowledge. it worked the way i wanted when i changed uploader to wb1. I see lot of pop up boxes as input. is there a way I can make get 1 pop up box which will ask me 3 things (your name? your Age? Your occupation ?) and I can give 3 answers which will get in 3 different cells Say Cell (3,E;4,E;5,E)

Comment: Yes you can but you would need extra code to check that the user had correctly entered the information. See here for an example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52aa7ec1-9663-432c-9449-55fb1d738969/vba-inputbox-that-returns-array-of-values?forum=isvvba

Comment: While implementing I ran into one more problem. The sheet I create using macro gets saved at the end. People use it and input value for current names.Next time the same macro is used the last file that already has values gets copied over with changed names. Is there anyway I can save the last file as empty template and then every sheet that gets created using macro will be saved just before the last worksheet(Empty Template)

Comment: I will try and help but it might be faster for you to post as new question with the relevant code, as it now stands, and a clear problem description and the desired outcome. I am unclear on the overall process (so detailing that as a flow of events with filenames would help - pseudo code to guide readers as to what you want). I am wondering if you could have a template file and open that each time, have the person complete this and code for it to save with a different name so you would always have the template available. Which file is intended to be the template?

Comment: It is one excel file with many tabs.The last tab is always suppose to be a template. and the new tab that get created by code is suppose to get saved just before the last tab( name say template). The code will work fine.Current code generates file based on last tab and saves it after the Template. Now second time I use the code it uses the already created tab since it looks for last tab

      ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

I see a way to do it is search the tab called "Template" and make a copy of it then use rename etc. Currently I guess it look for last active tab

Comment: Well described. Absolutely! You can access the worksheet name by .Name property. So you can code copy template sheet before template sheet (macro recorder would help you capture outline code for this).